# Testing a function and not getting correct result for .toHaveBeenCalled() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing the following function:

```
onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!this.state.measureURI) return
        this.setState({ foodId: this.props.food.foodId }, () => this.props.fetchServing({
            quantity: parseInt(this.state.quantity),
            measureURI: this.state.measureURI,
            foodId: this.state.foodId
        }))
    }
```

test:

```
    test('should test onSubmit prop for valid form submission', () => {
        const onSubmit = jest.fn()
        const fetchServing = jest.fn()
        const arg = {
            quantity: expect.any(Number),
            measureURI: expect.any(String),
            foodId: expect.any(Number)
        }
        const wrapper = shallow(<ServingForm food={food} onSubmit={onSubmit} fetchServing={fetchServing} />)
        wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', {
            preventDefault: () => { }
        })
        expect(fetchServing).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
● <ServingForm /> › should test onSubmit prop for valid form submission
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
      37 |             preventDefault: () => { }
      38 |         })
    > 39 |         expect(fetchServing).toHaveBeenCalled()
         |                              ^
      40 |     })
      41 | 
      42 | })
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using jest and enzyme to do unit testing with spies.

Comment: what is `this.state.measureURI` during your test run?

Comment: it just makes sure that an actual measurement is selected

Comment: does your test ensure a measurement is selected before running?

Comment: I  am not, can you tell me how I would do that, it indeed is due to that line, because I commented 
`// if (!this.state.measureURI) return` it out and then re-ran the test, and it works, but I am not sure how to ensure that measurement is picked in the test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test code never reaches the `fetchServing` call as `this.state.measureURI` doesn't have a value so it just returns at that point. I'm not familiar with enzyme, but according to the [docs](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/setState.html), the `wrapper` has `setState` functionality so you may be able to:

```
wrapper.setState({ measureURI: 'whatever' });
```

Comment: Thanks I simulated a call to change measure URI before calling the submit, and it worked `const value = "cup";
        wrapper.find("select").simulate("change", {
            target: { value },
        })`